# Identify graph type

Tags: data-structures

A graph with 1 connected component contains no circle and not a tree.

what type is this kind for graph?

I did a lot of googling and even look up all graph types on wikipedia,but didn't find one fit that criteria.

Comment: @nhahtdh Why directed? OP: Check out the definition of a tree graph and work from there.

Comment: Probably not directed, then. Just connected acyclic graph.